# Is the use of the phrase 'tip of the iceberg' correct in the following sentence?

Tags: phrases

The dimensions of learning are indeed endless, and the more we learn, the more we realize that we have only scratched the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a dictionary?

[tip of the iceberg](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tip-of-the-iceberg):

> a small and known part of something much larger and unknown

But there is also [scratch the surface](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scratch-the-surface):

> to deal with only a small part of a subject or a problem

So it sounds like a mixed metaphor. (Actually a rather *good* one.) Which is fine if that is what you intend.

Comment: Have an upvote for mentioning the mixed metaphor :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. It'll counter the downvotes I get for answering a "low quality" question! You scratch my iceberg and I'll scratch yours.